# bash: ‘/usr/bin/python3.7’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash

I have set the priority of python versions like this
[image]

After that I am checking python version, I am getting error: bash: ‘/usr/bin/python3.7’: No such file or directory

~$ python --version

bash: ‘/usr/bin/python3.7’: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `python3 --version`

Comment: This gives Python 3.10.2